# Index performance on Postgresql for big tables

Tags: database, postgresql

I have been searching good information about index benchmarking on PostgreSQL and found nothing really good.

I need to understand how PostgreSQL behaves while handling a huge amount of records.
Let's say 2000M records on a single non-partitioned table.

Theoretically, b-trees are O(log(n)) for reads and writes but in practicality
I think that's kind of an ideal scenario not considering things like HUGE indexes not fitting entirely in memory (swapping?) and maybe other things I am not seeing at this point.

There are no JOIN operations, which is fine, but note this is not an analytical database and response times below 150ms (less the better) are required. All searches are expected to be done using indexes, of course. Where we have 2-3 indexes:

- UUID PK index
- timestamp index
- VARCHAR(20) index (non unique but high cardinality)

My concern is how writes and reads will perform once the table reach it's expected top capacity (2500M records)

... so specific questions might be:

- May "adding more iron" achieve reasonable performance in such scenario?
  NOTE this is non-clustered DB so this is vertical scaling.
- What would be the main sources of time consumption either for reads and writes?
- What would be the amount of records on a table that we can consider "too much" for this standard setup on PostgreSql (no cluster, no partitions, no sharding)?

I know this amount of records suggests taking some alternative (sharding, partitioning, etc) but this question is about learning and understanding PostgreSQL capabilities more than other thing.

Comment: Test, test and test. We have no idea how your hardware behaves, what other processes will be active, etc. etc. Table partitioning might be of help

Comment: Thanks @FrankHeikens Thats undoubtly a good advice, at the same time you may guess it gives zero help. I think the "specific questions" are constrained enough in order to be answered with appropriate simplifications. Other database technologies just does not have problems with such amount of data ... so your answer I perceive more towards the side of being hardly for PostgreSQL to behave on the described scenario. Which is no bad and no shame since each database product is designed for specific problems.

Comment: PostgreSQL itself can handle this, no problem. But there is a massive dependency on your (virtual) hardware and of course the SQL involved. It's completely useless that I tell you PostgreSQL can do it, when your hardware isn't capable of supporting this, not matter what brand of database you run. That's why you have to test it yourself. pg_bench is always a good starting point and you can create pretty big tables using pg_bench. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There should be no performance degradation inserting into or selecting from a table, even if it is large. The expense of index access grows with the logarithm of the table size, but the base of the logarithm is large, and the index shouldn't have a depth of the index cannot be more than 5 or 6. The upper levels of the index are probably cached, so you end up with a handful of blocks read when accessing a single table row per index scan. Note that you don't have to cache the whole index.